# Compare two objects and return only the matched values from the first object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do a comparison between two objects and the matching values in the first object should be returned. For Example:

**Object 1**

```
[{
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Thomas",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "George",
  "country": "Nigeria"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Mark",
  "country": "Serbia"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Ronald",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Female",
  "name": "Jennifer",
  "country": "China"
}]
```

**Object 2**

```
[{
  "sex": "Male",
  "country": "China"
}]
```

The resulting object should be like,

```
[{
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Thomas",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Ronald",
  "country": "China"
}]
```

Is there any possibility to do this. If so yes, could you please tell how to do it?

Comment: Does object 2 have to be an array of objects or it is single object?

Comment: It's a single object only. @Zeshan

Comment: Ok see my solution below. It handle both scenarios either second object is single object or array of object. However I'm going to update my solution for this specific scenario as well :)

Comment: I have updated my solution for both scenarios please check. It's simple and nice one liner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lodash _.filter https://lodash.com/docs#filter

```
var results = _.filter([{
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Thomas",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "George",
  "country": "Nigeria"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Mark",
  "country": "Serbia"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Ronald",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Female",
  "name": "Jennifer",
  "country": "China"
}], {
  "sex": "Male",
  "country": "China"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create array to hold result

Loop through both objects

If one element angular.equals the other element, add it to the reuslt array

Return resulting array.

Comment: great..thanks. I'll implement and let you know. But @Delapouite has answered me to use lodash. Is that a better way?

Comment: @PratikInfanto Please see my solution using underscore is one liner solution. Also see underscore library it has loads o f useful utility functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var firstObject = [{
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Thomas",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "George",
  "country": "Nigeria"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Mark",
  "country": "Serbia"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Ronald",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Female",
  "name": "Jennifer",
  "country": "China"
}];


var secondObject = [{
  "sex": "Male",
  "country": "China"
}]

var finalArray=[];

for (var i=0 ; i < firstObject.length ; i++){
    for(var k=0 ; k <secondObject.length ; k++){
        if((secondObject[k].sex == firstObject[k].sex) && (secondObject[k].country == firstObject[k].country)){
            finalArray.push(firstObject[k]);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check following nice and clean solution using unserscore.js

```js
var a = [{
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Thomas",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "George",
  "country": "Nigeria"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Mark",
  "country": "Serbia"
}, {
  "sex": "Male",
  "name": "Ronald",
  "country": "China"
}, {
  "sex": "Female",
  "name": "Jennifer",
  "country": "China"
}];

var b = [{
  "sex": "Male",
  "country": "China"
}];

var result = [];

// IN CASE B IS ARRAY OF OBJECT
_.each(b, function(item, index) {
  Array.prototype.push.apply(result, _.where(a, item));
});

// result contains all the matched objects
console.log(result);

// IN CASE IF B IS SINGLE OBJECT
result = [];
Array.prototype.push.apply(result, _.where(a, b[0]));
// result contains all the matched objects
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey @Zeshan..thanks for your answer. But using 'lodash _.filter' made it so simple..!!

Comment: @PratikInfanto 'loadash' is super set of underscore :)